# Objective-C: changing values of one NSMutableArray automatically change values of another NSMutableArray that is assigned to it

Tags: objective-c

I am initializing two `NSMutableArrays` namely:

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

`firstArray` has some values in it and `secondArray` has some values in it too.

Then I assigned `firstArray` to `secondArray`:

```
firstArray = secondArray;
```

Now if I make some changes in `firstArray` it will also affect `secondArray`. For example, if I replace or remove a value at certain index from `firstArray` then that value will also get removed from the `secondArray`.

So is there any way that changing in `firstArray` does not affect `secondArray`?

Comment: After doing `firstArray = secondArray;`, why do you expect different behavior from what you are seeing? They are now the same array.

Comment: Yeah I know what I was doing, assigning first pointer to another, but I didn't know how to make a copy of array values that's why I asked this question to make my problem more understandable. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `firstArray = secondArray;` you're actually setting their *pointers* to the same value, rather than setting the items in the first array to be the same as the items in the second array. This means that you have made `firstArray` and `secondArray` the exact same object, rather than having the exact same values. If you just want to have a *copy* of the second array into the first, you just need to specify that.

```
firstArray = [secondArray mutableCopy];
firstArray = [secondArray copy]; // non-mutable copy
```

Comment: Thanks Stonz2. Your solution is exactly what I wanted. There was a small issue though i.e, after making copy of secondArray into firstArray like you did, firstArray becomes NSArray instead of NSMutableArray. So, if I want to make any changes in firstArray like calling replaceObjectAtIndex than it won't allow me to do so because its not NSMutableArray anymore. Therefore, the exact solution of my question is to make a mutableCopy of secondArray like this:
firstArray = [secondArray mutableCopy];

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` in Objective-C is reference type. So, by doing `firstArray = secondArray;` you actually saying that firstArray and secondArray are the same object. So, no matter how you will access it, thought firstArray pointer or secondArray pointer, you will be accessing exact the same object, so as modifying.

I think what you trying to achieve is to copy your values from fristArray into secondArray, it is possible to do by calling `copy` or `mutableCopy`

```
firstArray = [secondArray copy];
```

Comment: Hah- we both posted almost identical answers within 30 seconds of each other.

Comment: I think both good answers could be improved with a sentence about what happens to the original firstArray after the pointer is overwritten.  i.e. under ARC, it will be released.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that both array is of reference type not value, so both point to same address, so that if you change the value of one it will effects another.

Initialize first array using `initWithArray:copyItems:` initializtion.

```
NSArray *firstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:secondArray copyItems:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising both arrays like this

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:firstArray];
```

Hope this helps.